# Laravel / Command prompt under windows

Tags: laravel, windows, cmd

Im using larvel 8 and apache 2.4 under windows 10.
I need to convert docx files into pdf files, and i found a uselful python script [docx2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/). Now i can simple convert docx using windows command prompt with this command:

`docx2pdf example.docx`.

Theres a way to call this command in laravel / php?
I tried with this without success:

```
$command=escapeshellcmd("C:\Users\sciccia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\docx2pdf.exe c:\test\a.docx");
$output=shell_exec($command);
```

or with

```
 $command=escapeshellcmd("docx2pdf c:\test\a.docx");
 $output=shell_exec($command);
```

Both commands works great in cmd window!
Any suggestion?
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

I solved changing "\" with "/" so right command is:

```
$command=escapeshellcmd("docx2pdf c:/test/a.docx");
$output=shell_exec($command);
```

I hope will be useless for someone!!